# Python gives TypeError when passing url as function arg

Tags: python, selenium

My function is supposed to take a url as the arg and send the selenium webdriver the url to get.

I am getting this error:

```
>>> web.get_url('google.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: get_url() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is my code:

```
class WebHook:
def get_url(url):
    try:
        if "https" not in url:
            url = "https://www." + url
    except print("Url is " + url):
        pass
    browser.get(url)
    innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML") #returns the inner HTML as a string
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Bonus points if you can point me in a direction for why my `if "https" not in url:` still appends 'https' even if the url contains it.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Change `get_url(url)` to `get_url(self, url)`. Note that the first parameter will be self (ref to object) value for which will be supplied by python.   2. Use `if not url.startswith('https'):` instead of `if "https" not in url:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function `get_url()` is inside a class, you must initialize it with the `self` argument as so:

```py
class WebHook:
    def get_url(self, url):
        try:
            if "https" not in url:
                url = "https://www." + url
        except print("Url is " + url):
            pass
        browser.get(url)
        innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML") #returns the inner HTML as a string
        browser.implicitly_wait(5)
```

It should also be noted that there is no such thing as `try/except print` statement in Python. The `if "https" not in url` statement does not throw an error, but rather performs a boolean evaluation. Also, if the url does not contain `https`, then you cannot simply append the `https://` to it. Note that `http://google.com` would break your code as it would become `https://www.http://google.com`.

Instead, something like this would work:

```py
def test_func(url):
    if "https" not in url:
        print("{} is NOT using HTTPS. Replacing http for https becomes {}.".format(url, url.replace("http", "https")))
    else:
        print("{} is using HTTPS.".format(url))

test_func("http://google.com")
test_func("https://google.com")
```

Outputs:

```
http://google.com is NOT using HTTPS. Replacing http for https becomes https://google.com.
https://google.com is using HTTPS.
```

Make sure to also keep in the back of your mind that while *most* websites support both `http` and `https` protocols, that is not always guaranteed.